# Etherpad: setHTML API response is successful but updated html is not visible on etherpad

Tags: etherpad

When I create a new pad and use newly created padID in /setHTML API, this updates HTML and updated
HTML is visible on pad. But, when I use the same process for a pad where I'm creating sessions etc the and use padID in /setHTML, this call is successful but updated HTML is not visible on the pad. However, this is getting saved in DB.

Please help!

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the mistake which I was making in calling etherpad.The correct way is given below. This is working fine for me.

```
<iframe src='http://pad.domain/p/PAD_NAME?sessionID=sessionID&userName=userName&showChat=false&showLineNumbers=false' width=600 height=400></iframe>
```

PAD_NAME and padID are sam in my case. /setHTML is working fine when I use padID.